# Access a variable by name in udev?

Tags: udev

I'm trying to get access to the partition type (the one-byte field in the master boot record) in udev, so that I can set ownership and permissions based on partition type. The challenge is of course that while I want to set the owner, etc. of `sda1`, the partition table is actually part of its parent, `sda`. (Of course, there are actually lots of disks, not just sda)

I've managed to get the partition type of all the primary partitions imported into udev database entry each disk. This adds four ENV entries to each disk, one per possible primary partition. They look like this, as shown by `udevadmin info --query=all`:

```
E: LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P1=fd
E: LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P2=da
E: LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P3=00
E: LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P4=00
```

I can then get access to those in the partition device (sda1) by using an `IMPORT{parent}`. The partition number (1–4) can be found in `ATTR{partition}`. The problem is getting the type of *this* partition.

It seems like `ENV{LOCAL_PARTTYPE}="$env{LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P$attr{partition}}"` should do this, but it doesn't work. If you take off the leading $, the generated name is correct, udev just won't do the indirect lookup.

The only way I've found to do it is this awkward line: `IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo LOCAL_PARTTYPE=$$LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P$attr{partition}'"` which works because ENV entries are passed as environment variables to programs udev runs, and thus the shell can do the expansion and echo it right back.

I could also duplicate everything for each possible partition number (doable, since I'm only using primary partitions), but that strikes me as even worse:

```
$ATTR{partition}=="1", $ENV{LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P1}=="da", OWNER="grid", ...
$ATTR{partition}=="2", $ENV{LOCAL_PARTTYPE_P2}=="da", OWNER="grid", ...
⋮
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. For example: in the paragraph where you mention `IMPORT{program}="`, you refer to a method of *setting* a device property, whereas below that, you present rules for *matching* a device. Your description does not put it clearly, what is your attempt at each point.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: I'm trying to set ownership & permissions based on partition type. I'll make an attempt to clarify...

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: OK, I've done my best to clarify, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I don't understand why you are having problems with getting the partition type of a given partition. When I do `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda1`, I clearly have `ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0x83` and `ID_FS_TYPE=ext4`. Don't you have those or do they not satisfy your needs?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Unfortunately, I only have `ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos`, not `ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE`. Debian Squeeze apparently doesn't have a new-enough udev, or `blkid` rather. I suppose backporting util-linux would be an option.

Comment: Can you update the `udev` package? What version do you have?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: I have udev 164-3. I'd really prefer not to upgrade it, rather core component, and one which has a history of breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Honestly, I've never encountered any breakage due to `udev` updates, and I those occur not so rarely on my system (at least 3 this year, more than 5 in previous). But this might be contributed to the Gentoo dev team.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: You probably also get updates for other packages to account for udev changes. Squeeze only gets security & major bugfix updates (which is quite nice, as basically nothing ever breaks). Is there actually something new in later udevs that would help with the question?

Comment: I didn't check what package makes `udev` use the above discussed properties such as `ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE`. I suggested `udev` update, because I believe it must be either `udev` itself or packages it depends upon (which should get automatically pulled with the `udev` update).